# html5 file uploader/ move_uploaded_file issue

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I found a plugin an html5 file uploader I liked (resumable) and have everything working except for on the server (php) end when the file is saved to the hard disk. Maybe someone can have a look and give me suggestions? Because I keep getting the log error message, I suspect I have a problem with `@move_uploaded_file` and permissions? Alternatively, if someone could let me know where to look for any php errors, that would be useful too. I'm a beginner.

```
$temp_dir = '/public_html/uploads/'.$_POST['resumableIdentifier'];
$dest_file =     '/public_html/uploads/'.$_POST['resumableFilename'].'.part'.$_POST['res      umableChunkNumber'
// create the temporary directory
@mkdir($dir, 0777, true);

// move the temporary file
if (!@move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dest_file)) {      
_log('Error saving (move_uploaded_file)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you suppress error messages with @mkdir & @move_uploaded_file? Remove the @'s, write `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

`error_reporting(E_ALL);` 
at the begin of the script if you don't see php-errors and look which messages appear.

Also check your variables. You're setting $temp_dir but trying to create the directory with $dir.

Answer (score 0):

I've just applied some cosmetics and corrected a number of errors in the code. Had to assume some things. The temporary directory only needs to be created once (I guess?).

```
$temp_dir = '/public_html/uploads/'.$_POST['resumableIdentifier'].'/';
$dest_file = $temp_dir . $_POST['resumableFilename'] . '.part' . $_POST['resumableChunkNumber'];

// create the temporary directory
if (!is_dir($temp_dir) {
    if (!mkdir($temp_dir, 0777, true)) {
        _log('Error creating directory (mkdir)');
    }
}

// move the temporary file
if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dest_file)) {
    _log('Error saving (move_uploaded_file)';
}
```